# Is it possible to have a hot publisher with independent backpressure support for multiple subscribers in project reactor?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

My situation is the following:

I have a generator that generates random data. The generated data should be received by multiple subscribers. As the generated data is random, I can't use a cold publisher as there are several subscribers which will receive different data in case of cold publisher. Hence I need a hot publisher, but I'm not sure how can I make bounded requests from my subscribers in case of hot publisher. One of my subscribers task is CPU bound while the others task is IO bound, so the second one most probably will be slower. It's a little bit confusing how will the hot publisher behave in the following situation:

1. CPU bound subscriber makes unbounded request
2. IO bound subscriber makes bounded request, say 100 items at a time

In case of cold publisher it is clear that each subscriber can control the backpressure independently of other subscribers, so please describe how backpressure works in case of hot publisher and multiple subscribers as it seems that in my case the rate the CPU bound subscriber receives the data will be the rate of IO bound subscriber which seems to be not optimal as one subscriber depends on other.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on the hot publisher, but you can probably expect that at best it would follow the (edit: lowest) demand.

Edit: it all depends on the hot publisher, there's no general rule.

But conceptually they "share" their data between different subscribers, so in order not to overwhelm one of these subscribers they must either keep track of individual subscribers' requests and queue extraneous data accordingly, or perform a single request to their source that matches the lowest request between their subscribers. `Flux#publish()` (and by extent `Flux#share()`) [does the later](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxPublish.java#L411).

Comment: As what I've written in my question is just an assumption, can you please explain in detail how the hot publisher works with backpressure requests from multiple subscribers in project reactor ? Does it respect backpressure requests at all ? Or it just emits the data and doesn't respect `request(n)` requests made from subscribers maybe holding the emitted data in queue until each and every subscriber consumes that particular data ? Is there only one queue or one for every subscriber ? All of the above is not clear and I don't find any documentation on that topic